# use .html() inside .html() with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Have little calculation:

```
$('.sum-value').html(
    ($('.one-value').html()) * ($('.another-value').html())
    );
```

Want to calculate out of `.one-value` and `.another-value`. These values are numbers inside a html span with the corresponding class. So if I echo these two I get a single number.
And add the sum to `.sum-value`.

Is this possible or do i have to dump `.one-value` and `.another-value` to a `var`.
Actually it doesn't work, but I also get no error in the console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What elements are `.one-value` and `.another-value`?

Comment: html will return any html tag, I suggest to use text() instead, plus add a parseInt

Comment: No, you don't have to use variables. Please post more of your code and the HTML and create a jsfiddle demo. Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qt8ve/.

Comment: it's working fine to me. Here's my experiment http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/btGmU/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.sum-value').text(function(){
    var v1 = parseFloat($('.one-value').text()) || 0,
        v2 = parseFloat($('.another-value').text()) || 0;
    return v1 * v2;
});
```

We're using `parseFloat()` because we want to use the number contained within the `value` property, and we can't be sure it's an integer (in which case `parseInt()` would be more appropriate).

We're also using `|| 0` to guarantee that there *is* a number (in case, for example, the `element` is empty or holds a non-numeric value).

References:

- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: *"These values are numbers inside a html span with the corresponding class."*

Comment: @Felix: then the question was edited, I think; that wasn't there on the first reading. Also, updated to reflect the use of `text()` in place of `val()`.

Answer (score 2):

convert them into numbers

```
 $('.sum-value').html(
 parseInt($('span.one-value').text()) * parseInt(($('span.another-value').text()))
);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AAtvq/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.sum-value').text(parseInt($('.one-value').text()) * parseInt($('.another-value').text()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sum-value').html(function () {
    var n1 = parseFloat($.trim($('.one-value').text()));
    var n2 = parseFloat($.trim($('.another-value').text()));
    return n1 * n2;
});
```